# Are chrome alarms fired if the browser is closed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Do chrome alarms fire if the browser gets closed before the time it was supposed to fire? If it is called, is it called when the browser reopens next?

Comment: Only if you use [`"permissions": ["background"]`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions).

Comment: So you're saying it'll be called at next start up if i have the permission set?

Comment: No. As you can see in the documentation "makes Chrome continue running (even after its last window is closed) until the user explicitly quits Chrome" so your extension runs too.

Comment: No so that's the question. How are alarms handled once the user explicitly quits chrome...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set an alarm and close the browser, the alarm will fire immediately when you reopen the browser if the time for the alarm has expired.

If this is not what you want, you can try to put a session id with the alarm and then check on startup if the session id of the alarm matches with the current session, if it does not match then just skip over the code.